# How to assign many to many relationship in Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

Say each Businesses have many Catalogs and each Catalogs have many businesses.

Say I have a Business object. That Business object has 10 catalogIDs.

Currently I would use a proxy object. MutableSetForKey and then remove "differences". This is pretty cumbersome.

```
-(void)saveManytoManyRelationship:(NSString *) relationshipInDict andRelationshipInCoreData:(NSString*) relationshipInCoreData withTable: (NSString*) table andAttribute: (NSString*) attribute andDict: (NSDictionary *) dict andDictToSave: (NSDictionary *) dictToSave forBiz: (Business* ) BusinessToSave
{
    if([dict[relationshipInDict] isNotEmpty] && [dict[relationshipInDict][0] class]!=[NSNull class]){
        NSMutableArray * DownloadedRelationship =dict[relationshipInDict];
        NSMutableSet * ObjectsReturned=[NSMutableSet set];
        for(int i=0;i<[DownloadedRelationship count];i++){
            //NSDictionary * dictOfTag=;
            NSString * Value=DownloadedRelationship[i];
            NSManagedObject * thisTag= [self lookUpFromDictToSave:table withAttribute:attribute withValue:Value withDataCache:dictToSave];
            [ObjectsReturned addObject:thisTag];
        }
        NSMutableSet * manyManagedObjects = [BusinessToSave mutableSetValueForKey:relationshipInCoreData];
        //PO1(TagsReturn);
        [self removeDifferenceBetween2MutableManagedObjectSets:manyManagedObjects withDownloadedVersion:ObjectsReturned];
    }
}

-(void) removeDifferenceBetween2MutableManagedObjectSets:(NSMutableSet *) original withDownloadedVersion:(NSMutableSet *) downloaded {
    for (NSManagedObject * someObject in downloaded)
    {
        if ([downloaded containsObject:someObject] && ! [original containsObject:someObject])
        {
            [original addObject:someObject];
        }
        else if (![downloaded containsObject:someObject] && [original containsObject:someObject])
        {
            [original removeObject:someObject];
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the logic in the `removeDifference...` method: inside the `for (NSManagedObject * someObject in downloaded)` loop, the condition `[downloaded containsObject:someObject]` will always be true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy by using the Core Data auto generated methods (when you have Xcode create your NSManagedObject subclasses).

```
for (Catalog *catalog in catalogsToBeAdded) {
  [business addCatalogObject:catalog];
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
[business addCatalogObjects:catalogsToBeAdded];
```

There is no need to insert the inverse relationship. That happens automatically.

Also, you do not have to worry about de-duping. To-many relationships are of type `NSSet` so by definition there are no duplicates. If you add the same object twice, the second time will just not have any effect.